# grunt-sass and custom functions

Tags: sass, gruntjs, libsass, node-sass

I would like to create custom functions inside my grunt file (or everywhere) to use with grunt-sass.

I tried with this:

```
options: {
    functions: {
        'fakeList()': function() { 
            var list = new require('node-sass').types.List(3);
            list.setValue(0, 'a');
            list.setValue(1, 'b');
            list.setValue(2, 'c');
            return list;
        }
    }
},
```

But i correcty get `error in C function readFolder: Cannot find module 'node-sass'` (because node-sass in a nested dependency, not a direct).

So I tried forcing with a `npm install node-sass`.
But then I get this `error in C function readFolder: A SassValue object was expected.`

Did someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of the `setValue` method that must be a SassValue object!

I changed in this way and now it works:

```
options: {
    functions: {
        'fakeList()': function() { 
            var sass = require('node-sass');
            var list = new sass.types.List(3);
            list.setValue(0, sass.types.String('a'));
            list.setValue(1, sass.types.String('b'));
            list.setValue(2, sass.types.String('c'));
            return list;
        }
    }
},
```